# <div> background color and border won't display

Tags: html, css

I have 3 inline `<div>` elements that should have a light blue background with a black border, but the `<div>` on the far left won't display those.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
</html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css" />
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="inline" "id="clicker">
            <br> Atoms: <span id="atoms">0</span>
            <br>
            <input type="image" 
src="https://theatomandperiodictable.wikispaces.com/file/view/220px- 
Stylised_Lithium_Atom.svg.png/297637780/220px-Stylised_Lithium_Atom.svg.png" 
onClick="atomClick()" width="75%" height="75%">
        </div>

        <div class="inline" id="upgrades">
            <b>upgrades</b>
            <b>text</b>
        </div>

        <div class="inline" id="modifiers">
            <button onClick="buyElement()" id="BuyElement">Buy 
Element</button>
            <br> Elements: <span id="elements">0</span>
        </div>
        <br class="clearBoth" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="index.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
#clicker, #upgrades, #modifiers {
    width: 33%;
    height: 500px;
    background-color: #09a1a8;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 2px;
    border-color: #000;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 4px;
    float: left;
}
/*#upgrades {
    width: 33%;
    height: 500px;
    background-color: #09a1a8;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 2px;
    border-color: #000;
    text-align: center;
}*/

#upgrades button {
    width: 100px;
    height: 20px;
    margin: auto;
}

#upgrades text {
    margin: auto;
}

/*#modifiers {
    width: 33%;
    height: 500px;
    background-color: #09a1a8;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 2px;
    border-color: #000;
    float: right;
    text-align: center;

}*/

#modifiers button {
    width: 100px;
    height: 20px;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 10px
}

 body {
    background-color: #1e1e1e;
 }

div.inline { float:left; }
```

needed more textneeded more textneeded more textneeded more textneeded more textneeded more textneeded more textneeded more textneeded more textneeded more textneeded more textneeded more textneeded more textneeded more textneeded more text

Comment: I'm sorry about the "needed more text" but it wouldn't let me post.

Comment: You have an extra quote in `<div class="inline" "id="clicker">`

Comment: I fixed that and the background displayed. but now they are not inline. I have the width set to 33% so all of them should fit inline.

Comment: They are not inline because you haven't made them inline. <div> is a block element if you don't change its display property. class="inline" doesn't do that. You will want to add "display: inline" or "display: inline-block" to their style (possibly in the CSS selector for your 'inline' class).

Comment: always run your code through an HTML/CSS checker - this will help you find bugs like the extra quote that you have (and help you make standards-compliant and compatible code, too).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the first div coded as `<div class="inline" "id="clicker">`, when it should be `<div class="inline" id="clicker">` - the extra double quote is malforming the code, and confusing the browser.

**EDIT:** As for all being "inline", the problem is that at 33%, there's still 1% not being accounted for. Using percentages in this case also cause bad rounding problems (the bane of designers since the dawn of time), and you also have a margin - which is not taken into account normally - the 3 boxes are using over 100% of the available width, forcing the last one down.

I updated the code, setting them to 30% (a quick example, showing them fit. They may not fit perfectly at all screen widths). I would also like to recommend investigating `flex-box`, if you don't need to support outdated browsers.

```css
#clicker, #upgrades, #modifiers {
    width: 30%; /* rounding errors cause math problems */
    height: 500px;
    background-color: #09a1a8;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 2px;
    border-color: #000;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 4px;
    float: left;
}
/*#upgrades {
    width: 33%;
    height: 500px;
    background-color: #09a1a8;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 2px;
    border-color: #000;
    text-align: center;
}*/

#upgrades button {
    width: 100px;
    height: 20px;
    margin: auto;
}

#upgrades text {
    margin: auto;
}

/*#modifiers {
    width: 33%;
    height: 500px;
    background-color: #09a1a8;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 2px;
    border-color: #000;
    float: right;
    text-align: center;

}*/

#modifiers button {
    width: 100px;
    height: 20px;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 10px
}

 body {
    background-color: #1e1e1e;
 }

div.inline { float:left; }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
</html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css" />
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="inline" id="clicker">
            <br> Atoms: <span id="atoms">0</span>
            <br>
            <input type="image" 
src="https://theatomandperiodictable.wikispaces.com/file/view/220px- 
Stylised_Lithium_Atom.svg.png/297637780/220px-Stylised_Lithium_Atom.svg.png" 
onClick="atomClick()" width="75%" height="75%">
        </div>

        <div class="inline" id="upgrades">
            <b>upgrades</b>
            <b>text</b>
        </div>

        <div class="inline" id="modifiers">
            <button onClick="buyElement()" id="BuyElement">Buy 
Element</button>
            <br> Elements: <span id="elements">0</span>
        </div>
        <br class="clearBoth" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="index.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I fixed the extra ". and even your snippet is not displaying them inline

Comment: @zcool99 I just added an edit in the description, and changed up the CSS to show the cause of them not lining up.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you are putting text directly without any html tags.

**Try** `<p> or <h4>`

Comment: that has nothing to do with it. your able to do that in html.

Comment: It's working when you put <p> or other tags. Take a look.

Comment: the code has been updated to the working version. you can display text without the <p> tags, you just can't style it.